# Creating cv::Mat image from two-dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv

When I load 3d array of short int from binary file then I want to extract an 2d array from it and display image from 2d array as cv::Mat. I am getting "access violation reading location 0x0000002DABD00000". I saw similar topics, but none of them helped me to solve my problem. I am running out of ideas how to fix it.

```
ifstream input("short.bin",ios::binary);

    input.read((char*)&X, sizeof(short));           //X - cols
    input.read((char*)&Y, sizeof(short));           //Y - rows
    input.read((char*)&Z, sizeof(short));           //Z 

    vector<vector<vector<short int>>>Array3D(X, vector<vector<short int>>(Y, vector<short int>(Z)));    
    vector<vector<short int>> Array2D(X, vector<short int>(Y));                             

    for (int i = 0; i < Z;i++)                          
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < Y; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < X; k++)
                input.read((char*)&Array3D[k][j][i],sizeof(Array3D[0][0][0]));
        }
    }

    input.close();

    for (int i = 0; i < X; i++)         
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < Y; j++)
            Array2D[i][j] = Array3D[i][j][0];
    }

    Mat image(X ,Y , CV_16U, &Array2D); 
    namedWindow("Obraz",WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Obraz", image);
    waitKey(-1);
```

Comment: This is only a style suggestion and as such can be ignored if so desired :-). Instead of using `j`, use another letter that is less similar to `i`. I have seen instances where `j` and `i` get misread and a bug is subsequently introduced. E.g. I like to use `i`,`k`, and `n`. It may save headache later, or it may never be an issue, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

This statement is incorrect

```
Mat image(X ,Y , CV_16U, &Array2D);
```

The expression `&Array2D` is a pointer to a vector variable, it's not a pointer to the vector data. And in any case the data passed to `Mat` must be in contiguous memory but there's no such guarantee for the memory in `Array2D`. So this approach is fatally flawed.

To make this work you must create a 1D vector, and calculate the offsets for the elements in the vector manually. Then use the `data` method to access the contents of the vector.

Answer (score 0):

I found (with some help, to be honest) different solution for this problem. Check code below. Maybe this will help someone :)

```
ifstream input("short.bin", ios::binary);

    char* buff = (char*)malloc(312 * 45 * 248 *sizeof(ushort));
    input.read(buff, 3*sizeof(ushort));
    if (input) std::cout << "OK" << std::endl;
    input.read(buff, 312 * 45 * 248 * sizeof(ushort));
    if (input) std::cout << "OK" << std::endl;
    cv::Mat_<cv::Vec<ushort, 248>> hs(312, 45, (cv::Vec<ushort, 248>*)buff, 45 * 248);
    //hs(3,5)[120]
    std::vector<cv::Mat> vec;
    cv::split(hs, vec);
    free(buff);
    cv::Mat tmp;
    vec[120].convertTo(tmp, CV_8UC1, 1.0 / 256);
    cv::imshow("test", tmp);
    cv::waitKey();
```